# Mysqli Update from Paypal IPN Listener Not Working

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal-ipn

I have this script for a paypal ipn listener, which when run verifies the payment and does everything else it should except for a line which should update a database.

I have included the code below. The script is being run because the INSERT is working so I also know the SQL database connection is a success. Could someone please identify why when I run the script, the row links ends up blank.

Btw I know the user_id is correct.

```
<?php

session_start();    //start sessions

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];    //set user_id to session user_id

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}   //get the raw post data from paypal

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 

foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}   //get the IPN message sent from PayPal and set 'cmd=_notify-validate'

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    //post data back to paypal for validation
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {   //check if the data is valied
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    //create local variables from post data
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
    }


    include '../includes/connect_mysql.php';    //connect to mysql database with external file
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO tbl_payments (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime)
    VALUES ('".$txn_id."', '".$payment_amount."', '".$payment_status."', '".$item_number."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");  //insert transaction details into database

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_id='$user_id' LIMIT 1");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $links = $row['links'];     //find how many links the user has
        }

    if ($item_name == 0.10) {
        $value = 10;
    } elseif ($item_name == 0.25) {
        $value = 25;
    } elseif ($item_name == 0.50) {
        $value = 50;
    } else {
        $value = 0;
    }   //work out how many links were bought

$new_value = $links + $value;   //work out the users new amount of links

mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE tbl_users SET links='$new_value' WHERE user_id='$user_id'"); //update the user's link total  

$mail_From    = "********";
$mail_To      = $payer_email;
$mail_Subject = "Sucessful Purchase";
$mail_Body    = "Thank you for your recent purchase at our store";
mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);  //setup and send confirmation email

mysqli_close($connect); //close mysql database connection


} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";

}   //output error message if transaction failed

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: really... unless you want to support moronically braindead stone-age versions of PHP, you shouldn't even BOTHER compensating for magic_quotes. Pretend it never existed, and let the poor SOBs having to use those old PHP versions deal with the problems.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: And beyond that, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming your queries will never fail.

Comment: Fred-ii- Great suggestions tried it but unfourtunantly it still doesn't work. Likewise with die(mysqli...) still no errors.

Comment: Marc B I know the queries are ok because I have included die and there was no error though good point and I know I'm vulnerable but for know I'm not too worried as theres nothing of importance and I'm using paypal sandbox.